# Predicting new data in a binomial GLM

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

[Here is my data.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/os8wev5ttqvxcow/spacshu.txt?dl=0)

The question I had first asked me to fit the GLM, which I did with no problems. I got this equation of which I am very sure is correct.

> logit(Damage)= 5.08498-0.11560(TempF)

Then, I'm asked this:

> Construct a second plot that extends the range of the temperature data down to 30 degrees F. Do this using the following script to get you started:
>
> ```
> plot(c(30,85), c(0,1), type='n',xlab="Temperature (F)", ylab="Damage")
> rug(x=spacshu$TempF[spacshu$Damage==0],side=1)
> rug(x=spacshu$TempF[spacshu$Damage==1],side=3)
> ```
>
> Then add to that plot predicted responses for temperatures ranging from 30 to 85 degrees F as estimated using the model you created above.

By "above," it most likely refers to the part where I did this portion, involving a back-transformation.

```
spacshub.pred = exp(predict(spacshub.glm))/(1+exp(predict(spacshub.glm)))
```

My confusion starts here. The data (above, hyperlink in a .txt file) shows observations based on temperature and damage, with damage being a binomial variable, having only 0 (for not destroyed) and 1 (for destroyed). From what I read on binomial glms,

> Consider Yi to be a Bernoulli random variable for which we can state the probability distribution as follows:
>
> {P(Yi = 1) = pi, P(Yi = 0) = 1-pi}

Appropriately enough, when I plug in a value in R, it gives me a value between 0 and 1, and most of the shuttles that are destroyed according to the data had high(er) pi values.

Now here's the problem. When I'm initializing my new data, how do I go about doing it? Initializing the TempF stuff is easy enough, but what do I do about the damage? The predict command I performed earlier did not give me 0s or 1s, but a set of probability values between 0 and 1. How on earth do I go about initializing a new data frame with 30 to 85 degrees?

EDIT: Thank you, everyone. That helped, and I could make a prediction. However, I think there's something a little off with my coding. I'm also trying to make  a fit line, but I'm not sure how to change the number of elements my prediction has. This is mostly due to the fact that there is plenty of repetition in the data. So when I do this

```
newdata = data.frame(TempF=seq(30,85))
spacshu.predict = predict(spacshub.glm, newdata, type="response", se.fit=T)
```

There are only 56 elements, as opposed to the 138 in the data set. I can't map the fit unless they're equal. What do I do about my predictor?

Comment: If understand your question, you don't actually need to initialize the `damage` in your new data, because that's what you're predicting. The `predict` function just needs the predictor variables (`TempF` in this case).

Comment: `predict.glm` has a "type" argument that lets you side-step all this. Read the help page.

Comment: Thanks, I could make a prediction by using that command, but there's some further trouble I am having. I edited my post to reflect such.

Comment: If you want estimates at each original point then leave out the newdata argument. Or plot one with `points` and the other with `lines`.

Comment: Well, the question asks me to extend the range of temperature down to 30 degrees, which is different from the original data as the original stuff ranges from around 50 to 85. I think the question is asking me to make a prediction involving values from 30 to 85.

Comment: But you are complaining because you wanted more points than are in the vector `seq(30,85)`. So make clear what you want. It's either the number of points in the dataset or its the length of `seq(30,85)`.

Comment: @BondedDust, I'm not complaining, but I myself am not sure what the question is asking, so I wanted a set of fresh eyes. To quote the question, "Construct a second plot that extends the range of the temperature data down to 30 degrees F." Just doing the vanilla sequence code doesn't appear to give me proper fit lines, [as evidenced here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iiz0pg6e3iofx54/Rplot01.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

First to go back to the basics, you are working on a logistic regression model that has a binomial dependent variable (damage).
The logit function that you described:

```
   logit(Damage)= 5.08498-0.11560(TempF)
```

can estimate the **logit**(damage) for the range that you want (30 to 85 degrees F).

This will result in all different numbers for your logit in that range, have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean) to see what this logit value really means.

The values that you derive from you equation can be transformed to a probability with the equations you already described which will give you a value between 0 and 1. This is the probability that at a certain temperature there will (1) or will not (0) be damage.

GLM is just a way to predict the probability of a binomial variable to occur related to a continuous variable.

Hopefully this is enough to get your going for your plot.